# What are some examples of applications of quantum information to other sciences?

Tags: applications

I find looking at physical processes through the lens of quantum information science rather interesting. I know of a few applications of it:

- quantum computation;
- solid state (tensor network approach);
- cosmology (information exchange with black holes).

Can you provide any other examples? Maybe in high energy physics or even other sciences?

Answer (score 2):

You can model just about any physical or information system with a quantum computer. But you need to ask yourself (1) if the system demands enough computational power (processors) to justify the extra cost, (2) whether the problem solution is reasonable to receive per the delays inherent in sharing a scarce resource (time), and (3) whether your budget permits using a quantum computer (dollars).

Comment: You are talking about quantum computer (about which you are absolutely right). I was asking about treating physical phenomena like something that is involved in information processing. Looking for fundamental connections between physics and information. Like [Landauer's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landauer%27s_principle).

Comment: Look at Group Theory. Almost anything can be mapped into information processing. It just takes some imagination to do the mapping. My guess is that you are looking for physical measurements that pertain only to quantum mechanics. If so, the mappings are always there. But wave equations are hard to map because there aren't any good pictures. I am puzzling over mapping cubit states to a Ring. I am hoping that I can find a Ring with error-correcting properties. The tricky part is that the operators must be composed with gates. Neither is obvious at the moment.